# Proper translation of Genesis 49:10

Tags: hebrew, genesis, textual-criticism, prophecy, messiah

In Genesis 49:10, comparing ESV with NIV with NETS (Septuagint) with JPS with NKJV, all seem to be saying different things for the second half of the verse - which is correct?  This has major implications as this verse is used prophetically (especially the NIV and NKJV rendering).  Commentary on source texts as well as translation are both of interest.

ESV: "until tribute comes to him; and to him shall be the obedience of the peoples"

NIV: "until he to whom it belongs[b] shall come and the obedience of the nations shall be his."

NETS: "until the things stored up for him come, and he is the expectation of nations"

JPS: "So that tribute shall come to him And the homage of peoples be his"

NKJV: "Until Shiloh comes; And to Him *shall* be the obedience of the people."

Comment: The [Septuagint](http://www.greekdoc.com/lxx/genesis49.html) reads ἕως ἄν ἔλθῃ τὰ ἀποκείμενα αὐτῷ, καὶ αὐτὸς προσδοκία ἐθνῶν.